# Python match string and determine action

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python , and I'm probably overthinking this or something , but what I'd like to accomplish is:

I have a service/process which writes to a logfile continuously. It does not really output any errors but only shows wether it receives traffic or not.

Example:
**Sending keep-alive. Stats: KA sent: 1089, KA recv: 223**

The script should look for the 'KA recv: xxx" and determine wether it is more then 0 bytes. If it is , it should run another script (let's call it A.py) and if there are more then 0 bytes it should run B.py.

What I have now:

```
infile = r"/var/log/logfile.log"

important = []
keep_phrases = ["KA recv:"]

with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.readlines()

for line in f:
    for phrase in keep_phrases:
        if phrase in line:
            execfile("itworks.py")
        break
```

Well I was fiddling around some more and what's working is :

```
infile = r"/var/log/logfile.log"
important = []
keep_phrases = ["Keep-alives: recv 0"]
with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.readlines()[-20:]
for line in f:
    for phrase in keep_phrases:
        if phrase in line:
            execfile("/home/pi/Desktop/led.py")
else:
        execfile ("/home/pi/Desktop/led2.py")
    break
```

The led blinks 10 times and then calls the above script again. (Led.py blinks green if connected, and led2.py red if disconnected)

So @shep , indeed I'm calling an execfile from within the "itworks.py" (which is now led.py/led2.py)

I'm sure there's a better way?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you currently have?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but `execfile` is usually doing it wrong. What you have is fine but if you start doing things like defining objects in `itworks.py` or calling `execfile` from within `itworks.py` things could get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something more like this

```
with open(infile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(i in line for i in phrase):
            execfile("itworks.py")
        break
```